# For any planar graph $G$ with a cut vertex, we can always add a straight edge in some plane drawing of $G$.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, discrete-geometry

**Fáry's theorem** states that any simple planar graph can be drawn without crossings so that its edges are straight line segments.

Recently, when I was considering the drawing of plane graph, I encountered the following question.

**Question** Let $G$ be a planar graph with a cut vertex $v$. In some straight-line plane drawing of $G$, are there non-adjacent two vertices, $x$ and $y$ of $G$ such that we can add an edge $xy$ with straight-line segment?

> **Note:**  Let $G$ be a connected graph. A vertex $v ∈ G$ is called a *cut vertex* of $G$, if $G-v$ (Delete $v$ from $G$) results in a disconnected graph.

The answer to the above question is positive from some examples.

Example 1

[image]

Example 2
[image]

It seems that  convex or concave polygon theory will be useful, but
I don’t know how to rigorously prove this fact.